# Angular 2 app not working - Blank page

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Chrome browser, Angular 2 with TypeScript.  Following is my code;

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2 - Simple Reddit</title>
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/vendor/semantic.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('app.js')
              .then(console.log('app.js Loaded!!'), console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
    <app-reddit></app-reddit>
</body>
</html>
```

app.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NgModule }  from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-reddit',
    template: "<div>Reddit Clone! ... </div>"
})

export class AppReddit{}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { AppReddit } from './app'; 

@NgModule({ 
  declarations: [AppReddit], 
  bootstrap: [AppReddit] 
}) 

export class AppRedditModule{};
```

main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppRedditModule } from './app.module'; 

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppRedditModule);
```

My code compiles fine with the `tsc` command.  When I run it, I get the `app Loaded!!` message in console too, but it shows a blank page.
There are no Console errors or warnings.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you create a plunker for your code?

Comment: Let me try to create one.

Answer (score 1):

Does it show any error in console?
Did you create the project with Angular CLI?

Try to add catch to the main.ts: `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppRedditModule).catch(err => console.log(err));`

And try to add `<base href="/">` into `index.html` `head` tag

Unimportant but I have to say it:
In `app.ts` you don't need `import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';` and if you would need it, you can add it to the first import. But you don't need it.

Comment: No errors in Console before and after trying the above steps.  Didn't work either.

Comment: Can you inspect the app and make a screenshot of the element tree?

Comment: Hm:\ try this please: @Component({
    selector: 'app-reddit',
    template: `<div>Reddit Clone! ... </div>`,
    styles: [``:host() {
      display: block;
      height: 50px;
      background: red;
    }]
})

Will it show something?

Comment: Sorry, one typo:/
<div>Reddit Clone! ... </div>, styles: [':host() { display: block; height: 50px; background: red; }'] })

But I guess that you don't have and Angular CLI project, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162228/discussion-between-laker-and-sid).

Answer (score 0):

Please change selector in your component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-reddit',
    template: "<div>Reddit Clone! ... </div>"
})
```

You have typo in selector

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo in the question I posted.  I have corrected it.  Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Ohh sorry.,I answered too early @Sid.Can you create fiddle of this?